# Groupby() and bfill() with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I had DataFrame with ID, Tenure, and several variables:

```
 ID     Tenure      var1      var2
 A         1         NaN       NaN
 A         2         NaN       30
 A         3          40       50
 A         4         NaN       60
 B         1         NaN       NaN
 B         2         NaN       NaN
 B         3          40       50
 B         4         NaN       60 
 B         5          50       NaN
```

I would like to use bfill() to fill the value for ID with tenure less than 3, and is expecting the below output:

I tried `df[['var1','var2']] = np.where(df['Tenure]<=3, df[['ID','var1','var2']].groupby('ID).bfill(), df[['var1','var2']])`, it reports error.

```
 ID     Tenure      var1      var2
 A         1          40       30
 A         2          40       30
 A         3          40       50
 A         4         NaN       60
 B         1          40       50
 B         2          40       50
 B         3          40       50
 B         4         NaN       60 
 B         5          50       NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `loc` assign

```
df.loc[df['Tenure']<3 ,['var1','var2']] = df[['ID','var1','var2']].groupby('ID').bfill()
df
Out[146]: 
  ID  Tenure  var1  var2
0  A       1  40.0  30.0
1  A       2  40.0  30.0
2  A       3  40.0  50.0
3  A       4   NaN  60.0
4  B       1  40.0  50.0
5  B       2  40.0  50.0
6  B       3  40.0  50.0
7  B       4   NaN  60.0
8  B       5  50.0   NaN
```